# Correlating a continuous clinical variable with multiple measurements per sample with a gene signature?

Tags: regression, bioinformatics

I am trying to correlate a continuous clinical variable with gene signatures from single cell gene expression data. I used the UCell package in R to create a score (on the y-axis) for each cell from each patient. This score is the strength of expression of a specific gene signature in each cell. The x-axis is the clinical variable. Each patient has a different number of cells, which are all assigned the same value for the clinical variable.

What is the right statistical test for a correlation between the UCell score and the clinical variable? I did a simple linear regression, shown in the plot, but this doesn't seem correct since each patient has the same value assigned to the x-axis for all of the cells from that patient.

I have tried searching the forum, but, likely due to my lack of stats knowledge, couldn't find a straight forward approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a simple linear regression here is that each *cell* is given equal weight, while the number of cells differs dramatically among patients. What's presumably of interest is the relationship between mean UCell score and  your clinical variable *among patients*. Treating the *cells* as independent observations thus doesn't represent the data fairly; in this case you need to think of the cells as being *technical* replicates within each of the individuals of primary interest, the patients. See the [Technical Perspective](https://doi.org/10.1091/mbc.E15-02-0076) in Molecular Biology of the Cell 30: 1359 (2019).

A simple way to handle these data (which seem to involve at least 15 patients) would be to treat patients as a random effect in a mixed model, with the UCell score as the outcome and the clinical variable as the fixed effect. That will take the correlation of scores among cells within each individual into account and weight the results properly by the number of cells analyzed for each patient. This [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-linear-mixed-models/) introduces the idea if you're not already familiar with it; there are many pages on this site that describe the approach.